# LargeValueFormatter looks to be broken for locale English(Australia)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using LargeValueFormatter to format Y-axis values. It works fine for all the locales except for English(Australia).
e.g- it returns values like 4K, 8K, 16K etc, for all other locales but when I change the locale to English(Australia) it returns the same values as 4e03, 8e03, 16e3 ....

How can I fix this? My doubt is on the DecimalFormat instance as it uses locale internally.

Device: [Emulator, Samsung S7, Moto Z]
Android Version [8, 9]
Library Version (v 3.0.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because of locale issue. "E" becomes lowercase then regex is no longer work.

While waiting for official patch from MPAndroidChart, you can temporary fix by creating your own LargeValueFormatter, similar to original source code, but has small modification in constructor:

```
public LargeValueFormatter() {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    mFormat  = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    mFormat.applyPattern("###E00");
}
```

or change in makePretty():

```
private String makePretty(double number) {

    String r = mFormat.format(number);

    int numericValue1 = Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 1));
    int numericValue2 = Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 2));
    int combined = Integer.valueOf(numericValue2 + "" + numericValue1);

    r = r.replaceAll("E|e[0-9][0-9]", SUFFIX[combined / 3]);

    while (r.length() > MAX_LENGTH || r.matches("[0-9]+\\.[a-z]")) {
        r = r.substring(0, r.length() - 2) + r.substring(r.length() - 1);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: I already have a custom LargeValueFormatter. Fixing locale to US, as suggested by you, solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: BEWARE: this sometimes throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Haven't been able to find specific reason why. I just catch this and return number.toString()

Comment: @MakinTosH which LOC causes out of bounds exception?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just got a few crash reports from this method. No more info sadly.

Answer (score 0):

@anhtuannd answer worked for me. If you're using Kotlin change primary constructor to:

```
init {
        mFormat = (NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US) as DecimalFormat).also {
            it.applyPattern("###E00")
        }
    }
```